# Error while running sed command in perl cript

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to run the following command in perl script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $cmd3 =`sed ':cycle s/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{0,13\}[^,|]*\)|[^,]*/\1/;t cycle' file1 >file2`;
 system($cmd3);
```

but is not producing any output nor any error.
Although when I am running the command from command line it is working perfectly and gives desired output. Can you guys please help what I am doing wrong here ?
Thanks

Comment: Perl is a superset of `sed` so it doesn't make any sense to involve `sed` at all.    `perl -pe '1 while s/^(([^,]*,){0,13}[^,|]*)\|[^,]*/$1/' file1 >file2`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, I will take your advice on it. I didn't knew that Perl is a superset of sed . It worded for me but is there any option in this like we have in sed "i" to write the output back to the same file. Thanks again !

Comment: @tripleee Also this perl command is not working into the perl sccript. but I can use this on command line. What should I modify to run in inside a perl script ?

Comment: Perl `-i` is available just like (sometimes) `sed -i`; but then of course the redirection to `file2` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks but this command is not working inside perl script. how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

`system()` doesn't return the output, just the `exit` status.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Then how can I run the command in perl script itself.

Answer (score 1):

To see the output, print `$cmd3`.

```
my $cmd3 = `sed ':cycle s/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{0,13\}[^,|]*\)|[^,]*/\1/;t cycle' file1 >file2`;
print "$cmd3\n";
```

**Edit:**
If you want to check for exceptional return values, use CPAN module [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/IPC-System-Simple-1.25/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm):

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture);

my $result = capture("any-command");
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `sed` from inside Perl is just insane.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (F, '<', "file1") or die "$O: Could not open file1: $!\n";
while (<F>) {
    1 while s/^(([^,]*,){0,13}[^,|]*)\|[^,]*/$1/;
    print;
}
```

Notice how Perl differs from your `sed` regex dialect in that grouping parentheses and alternation are unescaped, whereas a literal round parenthesis or pipe symbol needs to be backslash-escaped (or otherwise made into a literal, such as by putting it in a character class).  Also, the right-hand side of the substitution prefers `$1` (you will get a warning if you `use warnings` and have `\1` in the substitution; technically, at this level, they are equivalent).

[`man perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) has a snippet explaining how to implement the `-i` option inside a script if you really need that, but it's rather cumbersome.  (Search for the first occurrence of "`LINE:`" which is part of the code you want.)

However, if you want to modify `file1` in-place, and you pass it to your Perl script as its sole command-line argument, you can simply say `$^I = 1;` (or with `use English;` you can say `$INPLACE_EDIT = 1;`).  See [man perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

By the way, the comment that your code "isn't producing any output" isn't entirely correct.  It does what you are asking it to; but you are apparently asking for the wrong things.

Quoting a command in backticks executes that command.  So

```
my $cmd3 = `sed ... file1 >file2`;
```

runs the `sed` command in a subshell, there and then, with input from `file1`, and redirected into `file2`.  Because of the redirection, the output from this pipeline is nothing, i.e. an empty string `""`, which is assigned to `$cmd3`, which you then completely superfluously attempt to pass to `system`.

Maybe you wanted to put the `sed` command in regular quotes instead of backticks (so that the `sed` command line would be the value of `$cmd3`, which it then makes sense to pass to `system`).  But because of the redirection, it would still not produce any visible output; it would create `file2` containing the (possibly partially substituted) text from `file1`.

Comment: Your question specifically didn't ask about `-i` but it's in a comment. If you need inline replacement as part of a larger script, calling out to an external tool which does it elegantly starts to seem less insane.